# Найти минимальный элемент в матрице и вычесть его величину из элементов, вокруг него

Tags: c++

**Данная матрица (N + 15) x (N + 15). Найти минимальный элемент и вычесть его величину из элементов, вокруг него. Матрицу рассматривать как замкнутое пространство. Числа генерировать случайно в интервале [-N-15; N + 15]**

Правильная ли эта работа с массивами? Препод гоняет постоянно переделывать, мол окружающие элементы обрабатываю не правильным способом. Я даже не знаю как сделать эту задачу иначе.
Если есть какой-то другой более правильный способ, то пожалуйста помогите, я новичёк.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int N;
    cout << "Введите N: ";
    int i, j;
    int** matrix;
    int p;

    cin >> p;
    N = p + 15;
    int w = 5;
    srand(time(NULL));
    matrix = new int*[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[N];

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) // ввод 
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {

            matrix[i][j] = -N + rand() % - (2*N);
        }


    cout << "Исходный Массив: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(w) << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int z, d;
    int min;
    int min_index_1, min_index_2;

    min = matrix[0][0];

    for (z = 0; z < N; z++)
        for (d = 1; d < N; d++)
            if (min > matrix[z][d])
            {
                min = matrix[z][d];
                min_index_1 = z;
                min_index_2 = d;
            }

    cout << "Min element " << min << endl;
    cout << "Index " << "[" << min_index_1 << "][" << min_index_2 << "]" << endl;
    int ii, jj;

    for (ii = 0; ii < N; ii++) {
        for (jj = 0; jj < N; jj++) {
            if (ii == min_index_1 - 1) {
                if (jj == min_index_2) {
                    matrix[ii][jj] = matrix[ii][jj] - min;
                }
            }
            if (ii == min_index_1 + 1) {
                if (jj == min_index_2) {
                    matrix[ii][jj] = matrix[ii][jj] - min;
                }
            }
            if (ii == min_index_1 + 1) {
                if (jj == min_index_2 + 1) {
                    matrix[ii][jj] = matrix[ii][jj] - min;
                }
            }
            if (ii == min_index_1 + 1) {
                if (jj == min_index_2 - 1) {
                    matrix[ii][jj] = matrix[ii][jj] - min;
                }
            }
            if (ii == min_index_1 - 1) {
                if (jj == min_index_2 - 1) {
                    matrix[ii][jj] = matrix[ii][jj] - min;
                }
            }
            if (ii == min_index_1) {
                if (jj == min_index_2 + 1) {
                    matrix[ii][jj] = matrix[ii][jj] - min;
                }
            }
            if (ii == min_index_1) {
                if (jj == min_index_2 - 1) {
                    matrix[ii][jj] = matrix[ii][jj] - min;
                }
            }
            if (ii == min_index_1 - 1) {
                if (jj == min_index_2 + 1) {
                    matrix[ii][jj] = matrix[ii][jj] - min;
                }
            }   

        }
    }
    cout << "Редактированный Массив: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(w) << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
        delete [] matrix;

}
```

[image: Фото с компилятора]

Comment: а зачем вам пробегать по всей матрице, если нужно изменить только элементы вокруг минимального? И почему бы не спросить у преподавателя каким он хочет видеть решение, т.к. его формулировка `окружающие элементы обрабатываю не правильным способом` весьма странная, учитывая правильность результата

Comment: Конечно неправильно, ведь минимальных элементов может быть несколько (на скриншоте видно 4), но представленная программа это игнорирует. Ну и копипаста - просто жесть.

Comment: @VTT тогда текст задания слишком скудный, много вопросов возникает, если минимальные элементы отстоят друг от друга на 1, или даже расположены впритык друг к другу

Comment: @timbars А это все надо было уточнять у преподавателя.

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью двумерного дерева отрезков с интервальными модификациями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаю вектор, в котором запоминаю все элементы с минимумом. Потом отнимаю все элементы возле них. Вся идея в том, чтобы убрать громоздкую цепочку условий, и заменить её на цикл.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int INF = 1000*1000*1000+1000;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int n;
    cout << "Введите N: ";
    cin >> n;

    n += 15;

    int matrix[n][n];
    int mn = INF;

    vector < pair <int, int > > v;

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = -n + rand() % - (2*n);

            if(matrix[i][j] < mn) {
                v.clear();
                mn = matrix[i][j];
            }
            else if(matrix[i][j] == mn)
                v.push_back({i, j});
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {

        for(int j=0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n" << "Min element " << mn << "\n";

    int toX[] = {-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1},
        toY[] = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};

    for(int i=0; i < (int)v.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Index [" << v[i].first << "]" << "[" << v[i].second << "]\n";

        for(int j=0; j < 8; j++) {
            int y = v[i].first + toY[j], x = v[i].second + toX[j];

            if(x < n && x >= 0 && y < n && y >= 0) {
                matrix[y][x] -= mn;
            }

        }

    }

    cout << "\n";

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```